# How to add symbol D with stroke in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I want use the Đ in my text when plotting the figure. Here is my code.

```
fig_msdc_gs.text(
    0.03,
    0.5,
    $\mathrm{\DJ}$,
    va='center',
    rotation='vertical',
    fontsize=alfs)
```

But I got this error:

```
\mathrm{\DJ}
Unknown symbol: \DJ (at char 8), (line:1, col:9)
```

I search this problem online and I still can't find a proper solution for my situation.

Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: You could directly use the unicode character 'Đ' see e.g. [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D_with_stroke#Computer_encoding)

Comment: https://www.toptal.com/designers/htmlarrows/letters/uppercase-d-with-stroke/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the unicodes for (special) symbols:

```
'\u0110'
```

for the uppercase D-stroke or

```
'\u0111'
```

for the lowercase d-stroke.